# RLS Adaptive Filter for estimating signal

Tags: matlab, filters, adaptive-filters

I am currently working on a project where i am to estimate a signal x_T using x_1 and x_2 with an RLS filter.

I have a problem where i don't quite get the results i am looking for. I think there is a problem with the filter coefficients. I don't know which ones i am to use.

This is what i have come up with that i need to do:

Using the first 9:5 minutes of xT [n], x1[n], x2[n], train the RLS filter and estimate the coefficients ai and bi.

xT [n] = Σ(i=0 to N) ai * x1[n - i] + Σ(i=0 to M) bi* x2[n - i]

Freeze the estimates ^ai and ^bi at the end of 9:5 minutes.

Using the last 30 seconds of x1[n] and x2[n], form an estimate of xT [n] for the last 30 seconds.

In my code i have the following RLS algorithm:

```
% Parameters
data_length = length(x_T);  
dim = 2;           
lambda = 0.9;   %  0 < lambda < 1
alpha = 100;
N = 100;
M = 100;

% Initialization
theta = zeros(dim, 1);
P = alpha * eye(dim);

% RLS algorithm
for n = 1:data_length
    % Form input vector
    h = [x_1(n); x_2(n)];
    
    % Compute a priori error
    error = x_T(n) - h' * theta;
    
    % Compute Kalman gain vector
    K = P * h / (lambda^n + h' * P * h);
    
    % Update estimate
    theta = theta + K * error;
    
    % Uppdatera P[n]
    P = (eye(dim) - K * h') * P;

     % Store theta values at each iteration
    a_koeff(n) = theta(1);
    b_koeff(n) = theta(2);
end
```

This means that i will have length(x_T) number of filter coefficients. First of all i am wondering if this is correct and second of all if it is correct, which ones am i supposed to use for reconstructing the missing part? I think i probably shouldn't have this many filter coefficients but only "filter_length" number of coefficients... I just cant think of a way to implement this.

Also for the reconstruction part, the problem here is i don't know which filter coefficients to use. If i like i do now have length(x_T) filter coefficients which is 71250, am i to use the first 3750 coefficients or the last?

Right now i am using the N first for ai and M first for bi as following:

```
% Reconstruction
x_reconstructed = zeros(size(x_missing));
for n = length(x_T):length(x_1)
a = 0;
b = 0;
for i = 1:N
a = a + a_koeff(i) * x_1(n-i);
end

for j = 1:M
b = b + b_koeff(j) * x_2(n-j);
end
x_reconstructed(n-length(x_T)+1) = a + b;
end
```

This seems wrong as the coefficients should get better the more we have iterated. I tried with using the last but then the results are even stranger. I will attach an image of the plots where i have the reconstructed signal and the missing signal.

Thank you!!

Full code:

````
% This file provides code for loading data for one patient
% The file assumes the DATASET folder is in the same folder with this m-file


clear all
close all
clc


patient_no = 2;
s=string(patient_no);

x_1= importdata('DATASET/ECG_'+s+'/ECG_'+ s +'_V.mat');
x_2= importdata('DATASET/ECG_'+s+'/ECG_'+ s +'_AVR.mat');
x_T = importdata('DATASET/ECG_'+s+'/ECG_'+ s +'_II.mat');
x_missing= importdata('DATASET/ECG_'+s+'/ECG_'+ s +'_II_missing.mat');

% Parameters
data_length = length(x_T);  
dim = 2;           
lambda = 0.9;   %  0 < lambda < 1
alpha = 100;
N = 100;
M = 100;

% Initialization
theta = zeros(dim, 1);
P = alpha * eye(dim);

% RLS algorithm
for n = 1:data_length
    % Form input vector
    h = [x_1(n); x_2(n)];
    
    % Compute a priori error
    error = x_T(n) - h' * theta;
    
    % Compute Kalman gain vector
    K = P * h / (lambda^n + h' * P * h);
    
    % Update estimate
    theta = theta + K * error;
    
    % Uppdatera P[n]
    P = (eye(dim) - K * h') * P;

     % Store theta values at each iteration
    a_koeff(n) = theta(1);
    b_koeff(n) = theta(2);
end


% Reconstruction
x_reconstructed = zeros(size(x_missing));
for n = length(x_T):length(x_1)
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    for i = 1:N
        a = a + a_koeff(i) * x_1(n-i);
    end

    for j = 1:M
        b = b + b_koeff(j) * x_2(n-j);
    end
    x_reconstructed(n-length(x_T)+1) = a + b;
end

% Plotting the reconstructed data
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x_reconstructed)
title('Reconstructed Data')
xlabel('Sample Index')
ylabel('Amplitude')
legend('Reconstructed Signal')

% Plotting the missing data
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x_missing)
title('Missing Data')
xlabel('Sample Index')
ylabel('Amplitude')
legend('Missing Signal')

```
````

Comment: Could you share the data itself as well? A `CSV` or `mat` file.